# ImageMagick first use issues (unable to open image logo.gif)

Tags: cmd, imagemagick

I've just installed **ImageMagick** and as the web site says, I was testing the following commands:

```
convert logo: logo.gif
identify logo.gif
imdisplay logo.gif
```

I opened a Command Prompt window in the directory c:\Program Files\ImageMagick and executed the commands.

1) **convert logo: logo.gif**: I can't say if something happended, because it just listed the possible commands of ImageMagick

2) **identify logo.gif**: it prints the error: 
*identify.exe: unable to open image 'logo.gif': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2645*

It appears that the command 'convert' it's not converting anything, but as it doesn't print an error when executed I don't know what can it be.

I'd appreciate if somebody could help me.

Comment: Well 2) was never going to work if 1) didn't, because it relies on the output of 1). So the question is "Why didn't 1) work?". Try your first command again but this time do "convert logo: logo.gif | more" then you can see the error messages and press SPACEBAR to get next screenful.

Comment: Also, try to find the program "convert.exe" and rename it as "IMconvert.exe" as it sometiems clashes with a Windows built-in program, also called `convert` for converting filesystems from FAT32 to NTFS. Then in future you would run the ImageMagick `convert` program by typing IMconvert rather than `convert`.

Comment: Also, check your PATH variable to ensure it contains your ImageMagick folder within it, `echo %PATH%`. If not, update Settings>Control Panel>System>Advanced>Environment Variables>PATH

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for the detailed comments.
I've checked the PATH and it's correct. 
I've changed the name of the convert.exe to imconvert.exe
I've executed again "imconvert logo:logo.gif|more" and there isn't erros messages. However, I've noted that it prints some information about the program an then prints what is in the "Desciption" section of this page (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/identify.1.html).

So, weirdly, it seems like it is executing the identify command instead of the identify command, but I did'nt change anything in the files.

Comment: *instead of the convert command

Comment: Huh? I thought you were on Windows? Why have you got Ubuntu manpages in there?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm on Windows. I sent an Ubuntu page because I can't send images(because I'm new here), so I searched on google for part of the text printed in the command prompt to get the full text.

Comment: Can you do `echo %PATH%` and paste the output?

Comment: @MarkSetchell The output was "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.8-Q16;" followed by lots of other paths.

Comment: I'm stuck! Try "identify -help" and "convert -help" to be sure you are running the correct ImageMagick programs.

Comment: Otherwise try uninstalling and then reinstalling the x86-static binaries as they are most likely to work... ImageMagick-6.8.8-10-Q16-x86-static.exe or the Portable version (last one listed on IM website)

Comment: @MarkSetchell Well, I've put the help commands and the prints were very similar, the same list of possible commands, altough the list in "imconvert" was longer.
Now I'm gonna try reinstall and then I tell if it worked.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I've installed the ImageMagick-6.8.8-10-Q16-x86-static.exe and it worked the same way as the another one. However, I noticed that if I write the command "imconvert logo:logo.gif" without space, it prints the known message, but if I let some space (imconvert logo: logo.gif) the message is: "imconvert .exe: unable to open image 'logo.gif': Permission denied @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2645"

Comment: Try opening a cmd windows as administrator.

Comment: @foxidrive Thanks, it finally worked!!!! And also thanks Mark for all your efforts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing the cmd as administrator apparently was enough to solve the problem.